Laravel RewriteRule on htaccess with "at sign" @ for profile names on URL
I am trying to create a rewrite rule on a Laravel project route; the most straightforward approach should be like this:
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)$ /someurl/$1
However, trying this on a Nginx server is not the solution.
Do you know a better approach for this?
For vanity purposes, I would like to create a nice URL with an @ sign that could point to another route.

Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please invest a bit of time to enhance the information you share. What do you actually mean by "it does not seem to be quote the solution"? This might be a translation issue, but the sentence is hard to make sense of. Also please add details to the question about what actually happens if you make test requests that should be handled by that rule. And explain how you made sure that such rewrite rules do get applied at all in your setup. Thanks.
